# How to integrate attiny85 with source files? Specifically changing Timer0 to Timer1 to avoid conflicting use of timers

Tags: arduino, attiny

I am trying to control a servo motor on a timer using buttons and the ATtiny85. I am able to use the ATtiny to make an LED blink at the push of a button but once I include the servo library my code does not work.

I have tried using the Servo.h library and the Servo8Bit.h library but neither work. I thought that the issue might be coming from one timer being used for two different things so I went into the Servo8Bit.h and Servo8Bit.cpp source files and changed all Timer0 to Timer1 and all TCCR0B to TCCR1B.

I receive these error messages when I try to upload my code:

```
/private/var/folders/kd/6b3mdhb90xl1rm2j9_dvn7vr0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/EDE8B1E7-9D65-436D-87B1-4534CFB3B4CF/d/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/libraries/Servo8Bit-master/Servo8Bit.cpp: In static member function 'static void ServoSequencer::setupTimerPrescaler()':
/private/var/folders/kd/6b3mdhb90xl1rm2j9_dvn7vr0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/EDE8B1E7-9D65-436D-87B1-4534CFB3B4CF/d/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/libraries/Servo8Bit-master/Servo8Bit.cpp:493:9: error: 'TCCR1A' was not declared in this scope
         TCCR1A = 0;
         ^
/private/var/folders/kd/6b3mdhb90xl1rm2j9_dvn7vr0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/EDE8B1E7-9D65-436D-87B1-4534CFB3B4CF/d/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/libraries/Servo8Bit-master/Servo8Bit.cpp:498:13: error: 'TCCR1B' was not declared in this scope
             TCCR1B &= ~(1<< CS02); //clear
             ^
Using library Servo8Bit-master in folder: /private/var/folders/kd/6b3mdhb90xl1rm2j9_dvn7vr0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/EDE8B1E7-9D65-436D-87B1-4534CFB3B4CF/d/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/libraries/Servo8Bit-master (legacy)
exit status 1
Error compiling for board ATtiny25/45/85.
```

The expected result is that after uploading the code I will press a button. After a specified amount of time, 10 minutes in this case, the motor should move but the code doesn't even upload.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is comment/uncomment the right choice in the header file `Servo8Bit.h`:

```
//Options
//pick one, comment out the other one out:
//#define USE_TIMER0
#define USE_TIMER1
```

and it'll be compiled with correct settings and so on.

You've probably tried to change 0 to 1 everywhere and failed because the timer0 and timer1 aren't the same. The timer1 doesn't have two control registers A and B unlike  timer0.